# ASP.NET Core Change Build directory

Tags: build, asp.net-core

Does anyone know how to change the Build directory of an ASP.NET Core project?  In the project settings under build, the output path is readonly.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "output directory of an ASP.NET RC2 project"? Do you mean, "output directory of the compiler?"

Comment: The output directory of the compiled project.  It looks like the default is "bin\Debug\net46\win7-x64"

Comment: Just out of interest; why would you want to do this? And is this about the build, or the publish step?

Comment: One reason to do it is so that all build output is covered by single "ignore" directive in Git or Mercurial.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET Core projects are built using the .NET Core CLI. The output can be controlled by adding options the command-line call do "dotnet build".

Example:

```
dotnet build --output bin/whatever/ --framework netcoreapp1.0
```

See `dotnet build --help` for all available parameters.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this from within Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm not sure. You would need to go exploring in how MSBuild wraps dotnet.exe. These definitions are in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet

Answer (score 3):

You can define pre/post script commands in your `project.json` in the `scripts` section. Even execute multiple commands, when you turn the `postcompile` from string to an array ["command1", "command2", "command3"]

Other **workaround** is-

Open your ASP.NET core project .xproj file in Notepad and change OutputPath

from

```
<OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)'=='' ">.\bin\</OutputPath>
```

to

```
<OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)'=='' ">E:\SanketTest</OutputPath>
```

Once done, reload your project and it will automatically build in specified location.

[image: build output path]

See if this helps.

Comment: This generates quite a few folders in the directory I specify: <projectname>\bin\Debug\net461

Answer (score 2):

Edit the `.csproj` file manually.
Set the Outputpath as desired:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
  <OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)'=='' ">..\bin\Release\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will still generate subfolders for the framework version and the runtime identifier. To remove those add this to your project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
  <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```